# Does on-disc artwork printing and finishing use a special coating?

Tags: print-design, print-production, packaging, screen-printing, digital-printing

When professional packaging printers print artwork onto the surface of optical disc media using the likes of a UV Digital offset [disc printer](http://www.tapematic.it/products/flat-digital-printers/2Print/overview), Do the printers then apply any kind of special coating / finishing effects to the discs afterward in order to achieve the kind of smooth matte effect which appears on the discs?

For example shown in the link [here](http://www.jeditemplearchives.com/images/SWReviews/Home_Video/tfa-blu-ray/disc-bluray.jpg) is an example of professionally printed Blu-ray disc artwork, It has a detailed smooth matte effect and it was probably printed with an expensive UV offset printer.

I would like to know whether the matte effect was achieved through an offset printer alone like the one in the link shown in the paragraph at the top of this description or would the smooth matte effect of been applied after the disc had been initially printed on and if so what kind of methods would of been used to apply the matte finish effect to the disc?

Answer (score 1):

[This website](https://www.duplicationcentre.co.uk/cd-dvd-full-colour-on-body-printing.html#?) offers services related to CDs and DVDs. By visiting the *"On body disc printing services"* page, you can see:

> - Fine lacquered finish – no smudging, no cheap looking white matt   priming surface, just a glossy protected finish

And also by visiting [this forum-like page](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/1549601), where some people discussed about buying spray for coating CDs, I understood that the matte effect isn't created, but it's first printed like what you're searching for and then they apply a layer to make it look glossy and protect it.

Comment: Actually I figured out that most optical disc media such as Blu-rays, DVDs, CDs, etc. are printed on using a Lithographic Offset Disc printer and once the ink is cured onto the discs with the in-built UV curing system it creates the type of smooth matte effect which was what I wanted to know how to do.

Comment: I misunderstood your question.